# Error passing field to views, How do I correctly pass the model field to the view?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a model field to the view to calculate the sum of time, but I get an error: Cannot resolve keyword 'hours_worked' into field. Choices are: car, car_id, date, deal_gts, deal_me, driver, driver_id, finish_work, gain, id, start_work

models.py

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name='Дата')
    car = models.ForeignKey(Cars, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автомобиль')
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Водитель')
    start_work = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Начало работы')
    finish_work = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Окончание работы')
    hours_worked = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name='Отработано часов')
    deal_me = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Сделки МЭ', blank=True, default=0)
    deal_gts = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Сделки ГТС', blank=True, default=0)
    gain = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Выручка')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Доставка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Достваки'

    def hours_worked(self):
        fw = self.finish_work
        sw = self.start_work
        hw = datetime.combine(date.today(), fw) - datetime.combine(date.today(), sw)
        hours_worked = str(hw).rsplit(':', 1)[0]
        return hours_worked
```

wiews.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from .forms import TripForm
 from .models import Trip
    
    
    def home_view(request):
        trip = Trip.objects.all()
   
    
        # сумма чвасов
        sum_hour = 0
        me = Trip.objects.values_list('hours_worked')
        # print(me)
        for el in me:
           for i in el:
                sum_hour = int(sum_hour) + int(i)
    
        context = {
            'sum_hour': sum_hour
        }
    
        return render(request, 'driver_productivity/home.html', context)
```

Tell me if I'm thinking in the right direction, or is it better to do the calculation not in the model?

Answer (score 0):

try this if you use property you can access call the method.

```
@property
def hours_worked(self):
        fw = self.finish_work
        sw = self.start_work
        hw = datetime.combine(date.today(), fw) - datetime.combine(date.today(), sw)
        hours_worked = str(hw).rsplit(':', 1)[0]
        return hours_worked
```

in views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import TripForm
from .models import Trip

    def home_view(request):
        trip = Trip.objects.all()
   
    
        # сумма чвасов
        sum_hour = 0
        k = Trip.objects.all()
        me = k.hours_worked
        # print(me)
        for el in me:
           for i in el:
                sum_hour = int(sum_hour) + int(i)
    
        context = {
            'sum_hour': sum_hour
        }
    
        return render(request, 'driver_productivity/home.html', context)
```

Comment: unfortunately did not help ( 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'hours_worked'